# How to find percentage of Similarity between 2 float vectors with the same length?

Tags: java, vector, comparison, percentage, similarity

I have 2 vectors with 8 float variables.

Each vector has different values.

What is the efficient way to compare those 2 vectors and return an overall percentage of similarity? (for example ~80%)

```
float[] emotion1 = {0.050, 0.200, 0.025, 0.225, 0.075, 0.175, 0.0125, 0.2375}; //sum = 1.00
float[] emotion2 = {0.10, 0.150, 0.175, 0.075, 0.225, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.2375}; //sum = 1.00
```

Comment: How do you define "similarity"? How about a correlation?

Comment: a) your code is incorrect  - a floating point literal in Java always looks like 0.05 and not like 0,05, no matter what country you are in. As you have written right now, the sum is not 1. b) What have you tried? What is the problem with it? You need to be specified - StackOverflow is not a code writing service, and you need to show your research in your question

Comment: I looking for a formula to find a similarity/correlation and return in one variable as percentage. I've found a lot of different implementations, but i wasn't sure which one is right for this simple case.
Sorry, my fault, gonna fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[] emotion1 = {0.05, 0.2, 0.025, 0.225, 0.075, 0.175, 0.0125, 0.2375}; // sum = 1,0
    double[] emotion2 = {0.1, 0.15, 0.125, 0.125, 0.175, 0.075, 0.1125, 0.1375};

    Set<Double> floatSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (double value : emotion1) {
      floatSet.add(value);
    }

    for (double value : emotion2) {
      floatSet.add(value);
    }

    int arraysLength = emotion1.length + emotion2.length;
    int totalElementsNumber = floatSet.size();
    double percentage = 100 - ((totalElementsNumber * 100) / arraysLength);
    System.out.println("similarity: " + percentage + " %");
```

Comment: I am not downvoting this answer, but it is of very poor quality - just the code and no explanation whatsoever. The coding itself is outdated in relation to Java-8.
You do not know what correlation the OP is expecting here. Please edit the answer.